# django does not serve images to template

Tags: django-templates

I am creating a form that includes an image upload. I can upload an image to the admin and can see it there and in my media/images folder, but the images don't show on page nor do I see them as attachments on the update page I created. I have searched the internet and tried all solutions I could find but it still did not solve the issue. What am I doing wrong?

MODELS.PY

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now_add=True)
name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
place = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
time = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
entry = models.TextField(null=True, max_length=3000)
your_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')

blog_objects = models.Manager()

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.date} -- {self.name} -- {self.place}"
```

FORMS.PY

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = BlogEntry
    fields = ['name', 'place', 'time', 'entry',  'your_img']

    labels = {

        "name": "Your name:",
        "place": "Where?",
        "time": "When?",
        "entry": "Your adventure:",
        "your_img": "Upload image:",
    }

    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
        'place': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
        'time': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
        'entry': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', "rows": "3"}),
     }
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def blog_index(request):
form = BlogForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('blog_index')
all_entries = BlogEntry.blog_objects.all().values().order_by('-id')
return render(request, 'blog.html', {'form': form, 'all_entries': all_entries})


def update_blog(request, blog_id):
   entry = BlogEntry.blog_objects.get(pk=blog_id)
   form = BlogForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=entry)
   if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return redirect('blog_index')

   return render(request, 'blog_update.html', {'form': form, 'entry': entry})
```

URLS.PY (my app)

```
urlpatterns = [
path('first/', views.first, name='first'),
path('delete/<int:player_id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
path('third/', views.third, name='third'),
path('second/<int:player_id>', views.second, name='second'),
path('blog_index', views.blog_index, name='blog_index'),
path('hello', views.hello, name='hello'),
path('update_blog/<int:blog_id>', views.update_blog, name='update_blog'),
path('delete_blog/<int:blog_id>', views.delete_blog, name='delete_blog'),
path('', views.index, name='index'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

URLS.PY (my project)

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', include('my_app.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls), ]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

SETTINGS.PY

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_web/static', ), ) 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
DEBUG=True                
ALLOWED_HOSTS= []   


 --------------> I tried to switch to False, and then changed Allowed Hosts to ['*'] but it did not fix the issue
```

HTML FILE:

```
{% for entry in all_entries %}

<div class="p-1 mt-3 border-start border-warning border-3 h-auto d-inline-block">
  <div class="entry">
    <div class="mb-5 px-4">
      <div class="w-100 d-flex  text-black-50">
        <div class="px-2 pb-2 fw-light fst-italic" id="author">#{{entry.name}}</div>
        <div class="px-2 pb-2 fw-light fst-italic" id="time">#{{entry.time}}</div>
        <div class="px-2 pb-2 fw-light fst-italic" id="where">#{{entry.place}}</div>
        <div class="px-2 pb-2 fw-light fst-italic" id="hashtag">#childhood #amazing #gardens</div>
      </div>
      <div class="" style="text-align: justify;"><img src=" {{entry.your_img.url}}" class="w-25 mx-3 float-start" alt="your photo"> {{entry.entry}}

        <br>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4em; font-size: 14px;" class="bg-warning mt-4 p-1 d-inline-block text-center text-danger" id="btn_edit"><a href="{% url 'update_blog' entry.id %}">
                        Edit</a>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4em; font-size: 14px " class="bg-danger mt-4 p-1 d-inline-block text-center" id="btn_delete"><a href="{% url 'delete_blog' entry.id %}">
                        Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, @n_che! Please double-check the indentation in your code blocks: some of the class/function definitions give `expected indented block` errors. I'm assuming your original program doesn't have these issues since you only mentioned images not showing. This might be helpful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @QuackE.Duck, thank you! My original code works fine, except for the images. Do you know if there might be something else in a code which could affect the image error?

Comment: I don't have any experience with that framework, so I don't know what the error could be.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
In

```
<<all_entries = BlogEntry.blog_objects.all().values().order_by('-id')>>
```

I should have excluded `.values()`. Without `.values()` it works.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! :)